When I try to compile Agda, I get linker (ld) errors with GHC and clang
Reference: https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started/hello-world.html#id1
hello-world.agda
module hello-world where

open import Agda.Builtin.IO using (IO)
open import Agda.Builtin.Unit using (⊤)
open import Agda.Builtin.String using (String)

postulate putStrLn : String → IO ⊤
{-# FOREIGN GHC import qualified Data.Text as T #-}
{-# COMPILE GHC putStrLn = putStrLn . T.unpack #-}

main : IO ⊤
main = putStrLn "Hello world!"

compile
$ agda --compile hello-world.agda
Calling: ghc -O -o /Users/trial/agda-trial/hello-world -Werror -i/Users/trial/agda-trial -main-is MAlonzo.Code.QhelloZ45Zworld /Users/trial/agda-trial/MAlonzo/Code/QhelloZ45Zworld.hs --make -fwarn-incomplete-patterns
[6 of 6] Linking /Users/trial/agda-trial/hello-world
Compilation error:
ld: unknown option: -no_warn_duplicate_libraries
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ghc-9.8.2: `clang' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)

I have tried the above, but it is an error.
I also looked at the following, but could not figure out what to do.
https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/24389
Should I wait for GHC to fix it?
My GHC version is as follows The version seems to be a little more advanced than the above issue (issue is 9.6.4)
$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 9.8.2


PS: My version of clang is below.
$ clang --version
Homebrew clang version 17.0.6
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin


Maybe this is superfluous information, I rewrote ~/.zshrc and tried to use gcc forcibly, but the error did not change.
~/.zshrc
alias clang='gcc-13'

compile with gcc-13
$ clang --version                
gcc-13 (Homebrew GCC 13.2.0) 13.2.0
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ agda --compile hello-world.agda
Calling: ghc -O -o /Users/trial/agda-trial/hello-world -Werror -i/Users/trial/agda-trial -main-is MAlonzo.Code.QhelloZ45Zworld /Users/trial/agda-trial/MAlonzo/Code/QhelloZ45Zworld.hs --make -fwarn-incomplete-patterns
[6 of 6] Linking /Users/trial/agda-trial/hello-world
Compilation error:
ld: unknown option: -no_warn_duplicate_libraries
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ghc-9.8.2: `clang' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)


a minimal Haskell program same error
hello.hs
main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "hello"

compile
$ clang --version      
Homebrew clang version 17.0.6
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin

$ ghc -o hello hello.hs
[2 of 2] Linking hello
ld: unknown option: -no_warn_duplicate_libraries
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ghc-9.8.2: `clang' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)

Haskell(GHC, Cabal, etc) was installed automatically at the same time when I installed Agda with brew.

What's your clang version?

@leftaroundabout Added clang and also included the results of a test with gcc.

Uh, I really don't think alias clang='gcc-13' is a good idea. But, the error is the same with or without that alias? Doesn't seem like GHC follows it anyway.

@leftaroundabout error is same. alias clang='gcc-13' is one of the attempts to somehow resolve the error.

Setting an alias here is a red herring, the shell alias wouldn't be visible to GHC.

Are you able to compile a minimal Haskell program (e.g., main = putStrLn "hello") with ghc Hello.hs without getting the same error?

@K.A.Buhr I am not familiar with haskell and have not tried it. I just tried it and got the same error. I have added the information to the question.

So the issue is there seems to be something messed up with your GHC installation. How did you get your GHC?

＠Cubic
As state:
Haskell(GHC, Cabal, etc) was installed automatically at the same time when I installed Agda with brew. In other words. $ brew agda installed a lot of things.（I don't particularly want to install Haskell, but it installed itself!)(This is probably the result of brew resolving the dependency on its own.)
